# url encoding using Flex navigatetoUrl function

Tags: apache-flex, url, encode

I want to post data to a URL on my server from a Flex app. im using the following

```
UrlParam = UrlParam + '&name='+ name.text + '&business=' + buisness.text;
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(UrlParams),'_self');
```

the problem im having however is that if i enter a business with an ampersand ("A&b.com") then the name does not send.

Does Flex have anything out of the box to do the encoding from `&` to `%26`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [encodeURIComponent()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/package.html#encodeURIComponent()) to encode each parameter.

```
UrlParam = UrlParam + '&name=' + encodeURIComponent(name.text) + 
  '&business=' + encodeURIComponent(buisness.text);    
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(UrlParams),'_self');
```

Answer (score 4):

use [URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html):

```
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://....");
var urlVar: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVar.name = name.text;
urlVar.business = buisness.text;
urlRequest.data = urlVar;
navigateToURL(urlRequest);
```